# React Context - How to detect which component is calling the context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const tableContext = React.createContext();
const tableContextProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [isTableOne, setTableOne] = useState(false);
   const [isTableTwo, setTableTwo] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
       setTableValues();
   }, []);

   function setTableValue() {
       setTableOne(result.IS_TABLE_ONE); // true
       setTableTwo(result.IS_TABLE_TWO); // false
   }

   return (<TableContext.Provider value={{isTableOne, isTableTwo}}>{children}
                     {isMetaTable? <LoadingComponent /> : null}
           </TableContext.Provider>);
    };
```

If the context is from MetaTable, I would like to show a loading screen

```
 {isMetaTable? <LoadingComponent /> : null}
```

How can I pass a value to the context to set the `isMetaTable` value to `true`?

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/route1'><TableContextProvider><MetaTable /></TableContextProvider></Route>
    <Route exact path='/route2'><TableContextProvider><Table2 /></TableContextProvider></Route>
    <Route exact path='/route3'><TableContextProvider><Table3 /></TableContextProvider></Route>
    <Redirect from='/' to='/route1' />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Create another state variable and pass its "set" method to the context provider - `<TableContext.Provider value={{isTableOne, isTableTwo, setIsMetaTable}}>`